# Not found generated Java source for a JSP file

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, websphere

As per the document ([http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21232487][1])

I have added this ibm-web-ext.xmi file in WEB-INF folder.

But not able to found the generated java file for jsp

I am serching in this path C:\Program Files\ibm\SDP85\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\

```
    <webappext:WebAppExtension xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:webappext="webappext.xmi" xmlns:webapplication="webapplication.xmi" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmi:id="WebAppExtension_1"
  reloadInterval="3"
  reloadingEnabled="true"
  additionalClassPath=""
  fileServingEnabled="true"
  directoryBrowsingEnabled="false"
  serveServletsByClassnameEnabled="true">
  <webApp href="WEB-INF/web.xml#WebApp"/>
  <jspAttributes name="keepgenerated" value="true"/>
</webappext:WebAppExtension>
```

Comment: Touch required jsp files or reinstall app, since if class for jsp has already been generated, source will not be generated again.

Comment: Yep. I have restarted the RAD and luanched that http://loc...:port/XXXX/default.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deleted the profile and recreated. Now It is working.